# session management without cookies

Tags: java, session, session-cookies

I'm trying to scrape data off a website using URLConnection. Need to track my login and session, but the website has apparently denied cookies.

I cannot see cookies from that website. What are the alternatives they could've used to save their session? I see URL re-writing could be one option.

How can I track my login/session in that website?

Comment: Are you asking for help on how to scrape data if the would use url rewriting or are you asking what other techniques the website may be using?

Comment: @MartinThurau I've figured out how to scrape data, my question is - how do I track my session in that website, since it provides no cookies/sessionId.... I was wondering what techniques the website might be using too, I only could come up with either URLRewriting or hiding sessionId in hidden Fields. Anyhow, how would I be able to track my session in a website that provides no cookies?

Answer (score 1):

Storing the Session ID in hidden fields is another option. Check out this [tutorial](http://www.technicalinfo.net/papers/WebBasedSessionManagement.html)

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

**encodeURL()** Use it to ensure session management is handled properly. It takes a URL in, and if the user has cookies turned off, it attaches the jsessionid to the URL in a proper format to be recognized as the session identifier.

When to use it? Every time you have a link, form action, sendRedirect or other URL that goes to the client and your application requires maintenance of a server-side session. You do not need it for server-side forwards and includes.

Comment: How do you use encodeURL() to manage your session to another website that does not give you any sessionID/cookies or session mgmt data.? I think it would  only be helpeful if I had control over that website/any session data on it...